# Submit Web Forms for Sites with no Attribute Data

Tags: python, forms

Very new to this, so please be gentle.

I'd like to create a script (Python preferably) to fill out and submit a web form; however, the webpage only provides a pop-up to fill in the form, and I cannot seem to access the attribute names.

An example is [this webpage](http://www.parknpayapp.com/), which I need to click on the green "USE THE WEB VERSION!" button in order to fill out the form.  When I view the source, it looks like there is no information on the resulting pop-up window, so I'm not sure which attributes to use.

Any thoughts or references are really appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind this is not an answer 
(1) Click on green button (2) Right click on the pop-up which opens (3) Go to inspect element (4) Crawl in that div tag it'll become clear to you that what source they are using. What I'm looking at its a form and POST method and that is mentioned in the source.

Comment: [Go to](view-source:http://www.parknpayapp.com/pay/index.php) it'll show you the source of iframe they've used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the source for the page, search for the string "Use the Web Version!".  In the anchor tag you can see `onclick="reloadiframe();"`. So search source again for "reloadiframe()" and you can find that the URL will be "/pay/index.php".  If you look at the source for the page:  http://www.parknpayapp.com/pay/index.php you can see the `<form>` tag with method `POST`.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Would you know how I can assign a value to the 'loc' control, since the possible values aren't listed in the source?  Specifically, line 38 in the source of your link.

Comment: That's getting a little more complicated.  Those are populated by javascript at runtime.  Look here: http://www.parknpayapp.com/pay/app.js (from line 17 in the previous source).